# Command to randomise MAC address in Virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I know that in Virtualbox you can go to `VM -> Settings -> Network -> Adapter 1 -> Advanced` where you can either set your own mac address, or **click the randomise button**.

I also know that editing the `.vbox` config file, you can find your Adapter and edit the `MACAddress="..."` field to set your own mac address. Leaving this field blank (`MACAddress=""` generates an error, not a random mac).

You can change the MAC address of a VM from the host command line with: `vboxmanage modifyvm "VM Name" --macaddress "address"` - ([source SU post](https://superuser.com/questions/679152/change-windows-vm-virtualbox-mac-adress))

There is no equivalent that I can see in the command line or config file, for **the randomise button**.

Since this functionality is implemented in Virtualbox, can we access it? Or do I have to find my own external mac randomizer script?

### [EDIT]

I discovered the `auto` parameter, but it doesn't work? `VBoxManage.exe modifyvm MyVM --macaddress1 auto` runs without errors but also doesn't change the MAC, according to the Virtualbox Settings GUI, and the .vbox config file.

Actually, it kinda works (the GUI doesn't update instantly), but it seems it resets other settings if you run `macaddress1` and no other attributes. It might require you to re-set/specify all settings for that VM when you run `modifyvm`.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to post an answer to your own question and even accept it. This way it's easier to figure out which questions are actually unanswered.